# Suppressing format and extra args warnings for custom printf implementation

Tags: gcc, printf, format-specifiers

I've written a custom printf implementation for an embedded environment. In this effort I have also added some additional specifiers for printing unique types and timestamps, among other things:

```
printf("[%T] time\n");
```

Perhaps this ones unique as it does not take any arguments, but rather has unique handling in the parser. Although this could easily be remedied by using a macro to always pass false data as needed. Or if it cause too much trouble I could make it more unique so it does not appear the same as other specifiers that *do* take arguments.

All other custom types I have implemented take arguments as usual. The only trouble I'm having is with the compiler's warnings:

```
test.c:130:32: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘v’ in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%v\n", type);
              ^
test.c:130:16: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
     printf("%v\n", type);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

These warnings can be suppressed by adding `-Wno-format-extra-args -Wno-format` compiler arguments, which I do (for now). But this can mask genuine errors like passing integers where pointers are expected, or legitimately not providing enough arguments for a given specifier list.

Is it possible to add *new* semantic checks to `printf`-style functions?

Comment: Adding new checks is not possible, there is an open [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47781) for this.

Comment: @ssbssa thanks for the link. The original report apparently goes back to 2011, so I doubt we'll see any real support for this in the near future. There is contention over exactly how to implement the feature. I don't understand why a rudimentary support can't be had with something that just designates that e.g. `%v` takes a `void *`. It seems pretty simple, but I know the GCC codebase is complicated.

Comment: Something like this was suggested in the bug report as well, see comments [#11](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47781#c11) and [#15](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47781#c15).